# Make parent div unclickable but children children clickable - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a scenario like this one, I want to be able to click the background div (red) through the top div, whilst still being able to click the top div's children (blue and green).

```js
function bgclick() {
  console.log('Background Is Clicked!');
}

function topclick() {
  console.log('Top Is Clicked!');
}
```

```css
#background {
  background-color: #f33;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.children {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" onclick="bgclick()"></div>
<div id="top">
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick()" style="background-color:#3f3"></div>
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick()" style="background-color:#33f"></div>
</div>
```

I have played around with *pointer-events: none*. This will only make one clickable and the other not. How can I make it so I can click the red one and get a message, along with the blue and green ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a easy way to get around this problem (op).

*pointer-events:none;* makes it so the mouse won't interact with the element. By default, *pointer-events* is inherited, so just set the children as *pointer-events:auto;*.

```js
function bgclick() {
  console.log('Background Is Clicked!');
}

function topclick() {
  console.log('Top Is Clicked!');
}
```

```css
#background {
  background-color: #f33;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.children {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" onclick="bgclick()"></div>
<div id="top">
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick()" style="background-color:#3f3"></div>
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick()" style="background-color:#33f"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

To make parent div unclickable but children clickable only use pointer-events.

### pointer-events

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer
> events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
> pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances,
> pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
> appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
> capture/bubble phases.

More about how it works here [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```
.parent { 
    pointer-events: none;
}

.child {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the markup by nesting the `#top` container into the `#background` container.

And then simply pass the event to the `topclick` method and add `event.stopPropagation()` to it to make sure just the `div` on the very top gets clicked.

See the modified code:

```js
function bgclick() {
  console.log('Background Is Clicked!')
}
function topclick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Top Is Clicked!')
}
```

```css
#background {
  background-color: #f33;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.children {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" onclick="bgclick()">
<div id="top">
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick(event)" style="background-color:#3f3"> </div>
  <div class="children" onclick="topclick(event)" style="background-color:#33f"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```